# cannot run matlab from imported folder

Tags: matlab

I'm having problems running matlab in my machine. I did not install it but copied it from a previous xubuntu 14.04 installation (folder was located in /usr/local/). When I run it from the matlab bin folder it says `command not found` (**but the matlab shell file does exist!**). When I run it from the applications menu icon (which correctly indicates the path to the bin) it says `Failed to execute child process "matlab -desktop" (No such file or directory)`.

**Edit**: as suggested in one answer, this was a problem of permissions. Basically, the file did not have execute permissions. Apparently when you copy a folder via `cp` command it only gives `rw` permissions (?). I solved the issue by applying `chmod 700` to required files.

Now I have a new problem though. When I run matlab I get this: `/usr/local/MATLAB/R2011b/bin/glnxa64/MATLAB: error while loading shared libraries: libicudata.so.44: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`. The library is in that folder though. Should I run some command to share it or export it? Don't know much about these stuff.

Answer (score 0):

When in the matlab bin folder did you run it with `./` ie `./matlab`?

Also depending on how you copied it the file permissions and flags might be incorrect. Use `ls -al`to check if the executable flag is set. If it isn't you can set it with `chmod +x matlab`

Comment: yes, I used `./`. But you were right about the exec flag. Very noob error. All files had 600 instead of 700. However, now I'm having problems with a missing library: `libicudata.so.44`. It seems copying folders is not enough when moving matlab!